# Tcl 8.5 exec calling Ruby : Not working as expected

Tags: tcl, exec

I want to do something rather simple.
If I run on the LINUX session:

```
ruby -e 'puts "yey"'
```

I get in the LINUX console:

```
yey
```

I want to use tcl's exec, so I use:

```
puts [ exec "/usr/bin/ruby" "-e" "'puts \"yey\"']
```

But I get an empty string!
Why?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to work so hard at quoting:

```
puts [exec ruby -e {puts "hello world"}]
```

Remember that single quotes have no meaning in Tcl, use braces for the same effect as shell's single quotes.